# Deleting a key value pair on each user object

Tags: javascript

I am having difficulty deleting key-value pairs on each user object

I have been using the delete method to try to delete the password object as so
return `delete Object.keys(users.password)`

```
function deleteManyPasswords(users) {
  /*
    This function take an array of user objects and deletes the password key value pair on each user object.
    E.g.
    [
      {name: 'Barry', password: 'ilovetea'},
      {name: 'Sandeep', password: 'ilovecoffee'},
      {name: 'Kavita', password: 'ilovepie'}
    ]
    Returns:
    [
      {name: 'Barry' },
      {name: 'Sandeep'},
      {name: 'Kavita'}
    ]
  */
```

Comment: `users.forEach(u=>delete u.password)`

Comment: If you are doing this  to prevent passwords from reaching the user there is probably a better way in the context of what you are doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map()` with destructuring. Destructure the properties you want to remove and return the rest properties from `map()`

```js
const arr = [ {name: 'Barry', password: 'ilovetea'}, {name: 'Sandeep', password: 'ilovecoffee'}, {name: 'Kavita', password: 'ilovepie'} ]

function deletePass(arr){
  return arr.map(({password,...rest}) => rest)
}
console.log(deletePass(arr))
```

The above method doesn't work for dynamic properties because you can't name all the properties. For that you can use the following way]

- Create a function which takes two function.

  - An array of object
  - An array which contain keys which should be removed.
- Use the `map()` function on the array.
- Get the entries of each object using `Object.entries()`
- Use `filter()` on entries and check if key is not present in the keys to be removed then remove it
- Use `Object.fromEntries()` on the filtered entries and you will get the result array of objects.

```js
const arr = [ {name: 'Barry', password: 'ilovetea'}, {name: 'Sandeep', password: 'ilovecoffee'}, {name: 'Kavita', password: 'ilovepie'} ]

function deleteProps(arr,keys){
   return arr.map(x => 
               Object.fromEntries(
                  Object.entries(x)
                  .filter(([k]) => !keys.includes(k))
               )
            )
}
console.log(deleteProps(arr,["password"]))
```

Comment: I personally like this method over deleting.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly this use of `map` function does?

Comment: @S.Orioli https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @S.Orioli Do you want the explanation of specifically this code or the `map` function? If you want the explanation of this particular code tell me I will add it.

Comment: @MaheerAli what you added is fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove an attribute by using `delete` Key.
Have a look below.

```js
var data =[
    {name: 'Barry', password: 'ilovetea'},
    {name: 'Sandeep', password: 'ilovecoffee'},
    {name: 'Kavita', password: 'ilovepie'}
]

function removeKey(items, key){

    items.forEach(item=> {
        delete item[key]; // remove the attr eg Password
    });

    return items;
}

console.log(removeKey(data, "password"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `Array.map` function and then call `delete` on each individual entry

```
function deleteManyPasswords(users) {
    return users.map((user) => {
        delete user.password;

        return user;
    });
}
```

Comment: if you are considered about that you could also just copy the user object and just change the copy instead of the original

Comment: fantastic, thank you everyone. The combination of Map and delete was required which i was missing